# UITextView is not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

I want to display one paragraph in `UITextView`. I'm able to put the content of paragraph in Text view, but I'm unable to scroll `UITextView` (Some of the content is not visible as it's not scrolling).

What I'm trying to do is:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
//allocate view
self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];textview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200, 275, 400)];
[textview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]];
[textview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[textview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
//[textview setText:@"Hi,I'm working fine with this space"];
[self.view addSubview:textview];
```

In this case, scrolling is enabled. Can any one tell me why it's not scrolling?

Comment: ...or just remove the line on which you set the `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

Comment: If you keep `[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`, how do you think it will work? You need to remove it to enable user interaction.

Comment: I don't know why you have added : [textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; Simply make it yes.

Comment: Here you set UserInterection is No then here user touch event for your this textview is not detect so this textview not scroll so just set it with YES and it will work othervise just comment the line [textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; or remove this line ..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

set `[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];`and I think you dont want to keyboard to pop up then you can hide the keyboard by implementing the uitextview delegate methode `-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{[textView resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: and also set the delegate in you code textview.delegate=self; and add the delegate UITextViewDelegate in your .h file.

Comment: I implemented the answer given by you people.But, nothing worked for me.

Comment: Either it is not scrolling or keyboard still showing..? And also the code which you pasted have [textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];did you changed the No to Yes?

Comment: Its not scrolling and also Key board is visible.I tried every possible way.Yes I changed it to YES.Is there any way to make vertical and horizontal scroll enable.

Comment: I think you have not enough content which enable the scroll. to scroll the text view you should enter the very large paragraph if the content of paragraph is hidden then you will be able to scroll.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.Now I added big paragraph and able to scroll.I implemented keypad delegate method given by you;But My Key pad is still visible.

Comment: Well, no need to implement delegate method.I just set :[textview setEditable:NO]; Now its working fine.Thanks.

Comment: use this code it is working fine I tested it and it working fine                       -(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}

Answer (score 7):

set `YES` for `setUserInteractionEnabled` property of `UITextView`

set this line

```
[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

instead of

```
[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: @bapirout hey dude Here you set UserInterection is No then here user touch event for your this textview is not detect so this textview not scroll so just set it with YES and it will work othervise just comment the line [textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]; or remove this line .. :)

Comment: @bapirout its not working ?? also first set the frame small with this and then try it, just give Rect like CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200); try this and post comment ..

Answer (score 4):

I have a ViewController that only has a text view with about 5 pages of text.

Here is what I did in Swift 4.0:

1. Very important:  Make sure you have auto layout set on the text
   view.  In my ViewController, I set my constraints to the text view
   to 8,8,8,8 with constrain to margins checked.  The whole thing does
   not scroll if auto layout is not set.
2. This is the code I used:

**Swift 4.0**

```
textForPrivacyPolicy.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
textForPrivacyPolicy.isEditable = false
textForPrivacyPolicy.isScrollEnabled = true
textForPrivacyPolicy.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
textForPrivacyPolicy.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `UserInteractionEnabled` as `YES`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line : `[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` in place of this:

```
[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

Paste this code

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
//allocate view
self.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];textview = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 200, 275, 400)];
[textview setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]];
[textview setScrollEnabled:YES];
[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[textview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
//[textview setText:@"Hi,I'm working fine with this space"];
[self.view addSubview:textview];
```

Comment: I implemented the answer given by you people.But, nothing worked for me.Note:My text view is bonded with segmented control.Any of the paragraph will be visible depending on selected segment.

Comment: @bapirout make your parent view property set to clipSubviews = YES and then check and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had setscrollable and userinteractionenabled to TRUE. It turned out to be a problem with Constraints. In order to fix this, click on your view controller in ur storyboard (the battery icon on top right), then go to "Editor"->"Resolve Auto Layout Issues"->"Add Missing Constraints In ". Fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

bapi rout , There is a property for the user interaction with textView. You have set it to No. If you want to perform scroll on TextView, You have to enable this property.

`[textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

This will help you.